# How to configure several environments (development/release) in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm building a Spring application and I want to be able to simply switch between different application contexts, e.g. development and release, such that different bean implementations can be used in any context.

Does Spring provide a mechanism for this?

Comment: Have you tried profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spring profiles and annotate the beans with:

`@Profile("production")`

You can then add an environment property like `spring.profiles.active=production` to select the environment you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add a application level variable. Say application.environment = "development"; Then all places you want to make the switch, check the variable value. On alpha, you should set the application variable to "alpha" like this: application.environment = "alpha".